# I am trying to loop through an array of all the alphabets and capitalize every other alphabet. any solutions?

Tags: javascript

this is the code i came up with:

```
var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
// console.log(alpha);
// console.log(alpha.length);
for(i=0; i < alpha.length + 1; i++){
  if (alpha.indexOf('a', +1) % 2 === 0){
    console.log(indexOf('a'));
  } else {
    console.log("didn't work");
  }
};
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: a,B,c,D,e,F............ and so on until z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ` is what you want to achieve, than you can do something like this:

```
var alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var result = '';

for (var i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
  if ((i + 1) % 2 === 0){
    result += alpha[i].toUpperCase();
  } else {
    result += alpha[i];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `(i + 1) % 2 === 0` ==> `i % 2 === 1`

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop with a step:

```
for (var i = 0; i < alpha.length; i+=2) {
  alpha[i] = alpha[i].toUpperCase();
}

alpha.join(''); // AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map your array and upper case every second character:

```
var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('').map(function(ch, i) {
    return i % 2 ? ch.toUpperCase() : ch;
});
console.log(alpha);
```

Comment: `[].map.call(str)` would be more efficient

Comment: You can use `[].map.call` too - saves you having to use `split`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with strings is that you can't edit them, once created they stay the same. Most actions on them create a new string.

To avoid doing this lots of times, we do the following

```
var alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
```

Convert the string into an an array

```
for (var i = 0; i< alpha.length; i++) {
  if(i % 2 == 0) {
```

go down the array, and for every other entry (`i % 2` gives us 0 every other time).

```
alpha[i] = alpha[i].toUpperCase();
```

convert it to upper case

```
 }
}
var newString = alpha.join('');
```

and finally make a new string by joining all the array elements together.  We have to provide a null string ie `''` because if we didn't provide anything we would join with commas (`,`)

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score -1):

```
var alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
for(i=0; i < alpha.length; i++){
  console.log(alpha[i].toUpperCase());

  //If you want to update
  alpha[i] = alpha[i].toUpperCase();
};
```